# How to best keep values for Lab names/States Enums Vs Const

Tags: c#

I am working on a electronic medical software and I am trying to figure out the best way to keep lab names. Currently the way I have been doing it is Via enums

```
public enum LabType{
CBC,LFT,HepB
}
```

Of course the list is going to get bigger. I can go with defining a class and making const variables.

Would that be the most optimal way or should I have a Table of all the names and figure use it from there.

Comment: This is going to depend very much on what your software is trying to accomplish and how the LabType is going to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are developing an application for labs, there are chances that you will need new test(s) to be added to that `enum` or modify the existing one, its better if you store those names in a table and build your `List` from database.

This will let you have customize your available test list and also add other fields like description, charges, etc.

Having it as a `enum` restricts you from adding new items are runtime. Suppose after deploying application, the management wants you to enter new test to be available for selection, you would have to modify your `enum` and then re-deploy the application/dll. Whereas having it in database will help you adding new test types and then they will be available in your application.

Having the value in table also lets your provide your user an interface to modify existing test's text or add some new test.

Answer (score 1):

I would answer your question with a question: how often do you expect your values to change?  If your enum values are fairly static and change rarely (maybe around the time you do a regular release), then keeping them in an enum could work.  You would just update them as part of your regular update cycle.

But, if they change sporadically and/or more often than your release cycle, then keeping the values in a database, XML file or some other document that doesn't require a recompile is probably the better option to pursue.

A compiled value would be optimal from a performance perspective; but taking maintenance into account, moving those values out of compiled code and into a repository of some sort is probably very valuable, too.